Content download in network tab under chrome dev tools or download timing inside postman takes long time for a small amount of data <1mb size
My response is of size around 300kb ,for these api calls it takes my app around 1.4-2 seconds to download it?
What can i do to fix this
Possible answers i know, is to decrease the payload size, what other things i can do and what is the core reason behind this?
FYI: backend server in my case is bit faraway.


